# Circle-CI ImportError: Failed to import test module Python 3.7.0

Tags: python, circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm trying to setup Circle-CI for the first time for my application. It's a python 3.7.0 based app with a few tests. The app builds just fine, but fails when running the test job. Locally the tests work fine, so I assume I'm missing some Circle-CI configuration?

This is my yaml:

```
version: 2.0
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.7.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: "Run tests"
          command: python -m unittest
```

This is the error:

> ======================================================================
>
> ### ERROR: tests.test_auth (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
>
> ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.test_auth
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 434, in _find_test_path
>       module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 375, in _get_module_from_name
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/home/circleci/project/tests/test_auth.py", line 5, in 
>       from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug'

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I have added now `pip install -r requirements.txt` but I get now:

> Could not install packages due to an **EnvironmentError**: Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info'

**EDIT:**

In addition to the answer, here is complete yaml configuration working:

```
version: 2.0
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.7.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: "Install dependencies"
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
      - run:
          name: "Run tests"
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python -m unittest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that a dependency 'werkzeug' is not installed. You might need to install additional packages which are required separately.

Consider adding the dependency installations to the Dockerfile something like below

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

If you get permission denied issues, then your tests are started with a user who have no privileges to manage python. But its unlikely to be so.

Comment: yes, that was the issue, but I still had to solve that with the permission by creating a virtual environment. In addition to your answer I'll post the who configuration which is working now. thank you.